# Odd __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ value

Tags: c++

Following skeleton code:

```
struct Real
{
  virtual void method() const{}
};

typedef int (*function_t)(int);
typedef void (Real::*method_t)() const;

function_t f1()
{
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  return NULL;
}

method_t f2()
{
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  return NULL;
}
```

produces output:

```
int (* f1())(int)
void (Real::* f2())()const
```

while compiling with gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5). This is too unclear for me, I think it must be:

```
int (*)(int) f1()
void (Real::*)()const f2()
```

Why? Maybe it's a compiler bug?

Comment: It doesn’t “have to be” anything specific. It’s implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int (* f1())(int)` is a function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to a function that takes an argument of type `int` and returns `int`. C declaration syntax is sort of inside out sometimes.